# Sum elements of static array in compile-time

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm trying to sum ​​the elements of a static array in compile-time via templates:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<size_t idx, int* arr>
struct static_accumulate : 
       std::integral_constant<size_t, arr[idx] + static_accumulate<idx - 1, arr>::value>
{   };

template<int* arr>
struct static_accumulate<0, arr> : std::integral_constant<size_t, arr[0]>
{   };

constexpr int arr[9] = {1, 2, 3, 
                        4, 5, 6,
                        7, 8, 9};

int main()
{   
    std::cout<<static_accumulate<8, arr>::value;
}
```

but I got this compile-error:

> error: could not convert template argument ‘arr’ to ‘int*’

compiler - gcc 4.7.

How I can avoid it?

Comment: You might just want to take a look at constexpr with C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your template arguments to `int const * arr`.

Clang's error message is actually more helpful here than gcc's:

```
sum.cc:19:37: error: non-type template argument of type 
                     'int const[9]' cannot be converted to 
                     a value of type 'int *'
```